# express-jwt and express-graphql: error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'

Tags: typescript, express-jwt, express-graphql

I try to make express-jwt and graphql work together in typescript.

```
import * as express from 'express'
import * as expressGraphql from 'express-graphql'
import * as expressJwt from 'express-jwt'

import schema from './api/schemas'
import rootValue from './api/resolvers'

const app = express()

app.use(
  expressJwt({
    credentialsRequired: false,
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
  })
)

app.use(
  '/',
  expressGraphql((req, res, graphQLParams) => ({
    schema,
    rootValue,
    context: {
      user: req.user
    }
  }))
)
```

I imported the relative typings `@types/express`, `@types/express-graphql` and `@types/express-jwt`.

There is a typescript error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'
```

`user` is added on the request object by `express-jwt`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extends Express `Request` with one property

```
interface AuthRequest extends express.Request {
  user?: string
}

app.use(
  '/',
  expressGraphql((req: AuthRequest, res, graphQLParams) => ({
    schema,
    rootValue,
    context: {
      user: req.user
    }
  }))
)
```